# How to find in nested array (two level at least)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following json:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561f7896d3e4d2d8a6406baa"),
    "array" : [ 
        {
          "inProgress" : false
            "array2" : [ 
                {
                    "taskId" : 1,
                    "finished" : false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to find and test if both flags (inProgress and finished) are true. How to do this? I tried anyway, with find, elemmatch ... to no avail.

I can't lose the structure of the document.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the data set below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "561f7896d3e4d2d8a6406baa",
    "array": [
      {
        "inProgress": true,
        "array2": [
          {
            "taskId": 1,
            "finished": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Using aggregate pipeline to unwind and filter array as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$array"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "array.inProgress": true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "array.inProgress": 1,
      "array.array2": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$array.array2",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$item.finished",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      array: {
        $push: "$array"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

giving output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "561f7896d3e4d2d8a6406baa",
    "array": [
      {
        "array2": [
          {
            "finished": true,
            "taskId": 1
          }
        ],
        "inProgress": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem now is that when finished is false, it leaves array2 blank. How to solve it? The idea is to filter even between the two flags, as if it were an and (inProgress & finished).

Comment: you want to check either inProgress=true or isFinished=true to return full document if any one of them is true not both of them true?

Comment: Both true. However, when I have a record with "finished": false, I can't return $ array2[], but hide the $array.

Comment: Look at the link (https://mongoplayground.net/p/nO7ghsJrarb). I need that when array2 is empty, not return this block of structure (finished: false). Thanks.

Comment: Done. Is this the only solution to get the result I need?